# Loop Back to First Image Carousel Slider

Tags: javascript, shopify, carousel

I'm having trouble with my product image slider, when it gets to the end the Shopify default no image gets returned. I'd like it to loop back to the first image instead, so that the user can go back to first product featured image. Here's the essential code, any help on this greatly appreciated.

***HTML***

```
<div class="product-gallery container">
 <button id="left-btn"><i class="arrow"></i></button>
  <img class="product-gallery--viewport--figure" id="carousel" src=""  />
  <button id="right-btn"><i class="arrow"></i></button>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
 .container {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 315px;
}
.container::after {
  margin-bottom: 315px;
}
.container img {
    z-index: -2;
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
}

button .arrow {
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    outline: none;
}


#right-btn .arrow {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
}


#left-btn .arrow {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
}

#left-btn {
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 20.5%;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
}

#right-btn {
    z-index: 0;
    left: 45.5%;
    top: 20.5%;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
}
```

***JavaScript***

```
const img = document.getElementById('carousel');
const rightBtn = document.getElementById('right-btn');
const leftBtn = document.getElementById('left-btn');

// Pull images from Shopify CDN
 let pictures =  [{{ product.media[0] | img_url: '500x' | json }},{{ product.media[1] | img_url: '500x' | json }},{{ product.media[2].src | img_url: '500x' | json }},{{ product.media[3].src | img_url: '500x' | json }},{{ product.media[4].src | img_url: '500x' | json }},{{ product.media[5].src | img_url: '500x' | json }},{{ product.media[6].src | img_url: '500x' | json }}];

img.src = pictures[0];
let position = 0;

const moveRight = () => {
    if (position >= pictures.length - 1) {
        position = 0;
        img.src = pictures[position];
        return;
    }
    img.src = pictures[position + 1];
    position++;
}

const moveLeft = () => {
    if (position < 1) {
        position = pictures.length - 1;
        img.src = pictures[position];
        return;
    }
    img.src = pictures[position - 1];
    position--;
}

rightBtn.addEventListener("click", moveRight);
leftBtn.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Btw,  you forgot a `;` at the end of the line `position = 0`.

Comment: Please explain the structure of the "pictures" array as it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Yogi - the pictures array is just fetching the product image including variant images from Shopify, each array item is a liquid object more info: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects

Comment: More information is required.  Shopify uses a default product image when no image has been uploaded.  So, the default image may appear anywhere in the array and in multiple places.  You need a way to filter these images from the array.  Please include a sample of the picture data after it is rendered by Liquid.  We need to see what properties are available to filter the images. Alternatively, you can ask this question on the [Shopify forum](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/bd-p/shopify-discussion) since it is very specific to their API.